# I will send a lot of emails with PHPMailer should I keep the connection open?

Tags: php, phpmailer

Well i will use PHPMailer to send a lot of emails via cron.

Should i open the connection with smtp server just once? or open and close it every send?

i'll do something like it:

```
while( ...
{
OPEN SMTP

SEND

CLOSE SMTP
}
```

or

```
OPEN SMTP
while( ...
{

SEND

}
CLOSE SMTP
```

I mean about performance.

thanks.

obs: it's not same msg, each email will reiceve a different msg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One connection should work fine. Havin multiple will overload the server processor